# casting error on xcode when using address book delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I copied this method, line by line from the apple dev library and getting casting errors for the two NSString casts. How can those be resolved? (I am using ARC)

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
        (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                         kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
self.firstName.text = name;

name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
self.lastName.text = name;

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

return NO;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are using ARC.

ARC forbids standard casts between pointers to Objective-C objects and pointers of other types, including pointers to CoreFoundation objects.

The following code, which is correct under manual memory management, does not compile with ARC:

```
NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                             kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

To make it compile with ARC, you need to annotate the cast. See [bridged casts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts).

```
NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                               kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

The `__bridge_transfer` annotation moves the value into ARC and *transfers ownership*, i.e., it tells ARC that this object is already retained, and that ARC doesn't need to retain it again.

Comment: actually, false alarm - looks like self.lastName.text is still null...there was just not an compilation error. any ideas?

Comment: @TommyG make sure `self.lastName` is not nil

Answer (score 2):

Try this kind of casting, instead:

```
CFStringRef name = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

self.lastName.text = (__bridge NSString *) name;
```

`CFStringRef` and `NSString *` are ["toll free bridged"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) (documentation linked for you), but the compiler is looking for a Core Foundation type being returned from your `ABRecordCopyValue` call.  So my lines up there use a Core Foundation type.  And then when you assign it to the label, you can then cast *name* to a `NSString *` type.

Here's more information on [Toll Free Bridging with ARC being involved](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5).

Comment: getting the same error on your second line (Xcode suggests I used bridge, but that doesnt work either (gives me Null when I NSLog it)

Comment: what gives you `NULL`?  `self.lastName` or `self.lastName.text` or `name` or?  if you set a breakpoint on your `ABRecordCopyValue` line, does anything get assigned to `name` or does it stay `NULL`?  If it does, then I suspect the parameters you're passing to `ABRecordCopyValue` are wrong.

Comment: just checked, "name" gets the right value. I am getting self.lastName.text Null if I listen to Xcode and add _bridge in the casting: self.lastName.text = (__bridge NSString *) name; otherwise i get an error for this line.

Comment: @albertamg has it right... would have been nice if you had mentioned ARC in your question.  I'm modifying my answer to have it make more sense.

Comment: The __bridge_transfer (rather than just __bridge) is significant there. Otherwise the ref count will be off by 1.